# Executing a razor view dynamically

Tags: .net, asp.net, razor

Is there a way to execute a razor view dynamically? If I have the view code as a string, can I execute it and pass it a model as a parameter for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked about, but has some interesting info on using dynamically generated templates: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/

Comment: That was the foundation work for our RazorEngine project on CodePlex. http://razorengine.codeplex.com